# How to properly escaping qsub command with long input args within ssh command?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh

I have a complex qsub command to run remotely.

```
PROJECT_NAME_TEXT="TEST PROJECT"
PACK_ORGANIZATION="--source-organization \'MY, ORGANIZATION\'"
CONTACT_NAME="--contact-name \'Tom Riddle\'"
PROJECT_NAME_PACK="--project-name \"${PROJECT_NAME_TEXT}\""


INPUTARGS="${PACK_ORGANIZATION} ${CONTACT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME_PACK}"

ssh mycluster "qsub -v argv="$INPUTARGS" -l walltime=10:00:00 -l vmem=8GB -l nodes=1:ppn=4 /myscript_path/run.script"
```

The problem is the remote cluster doesn't recognise the qsub command, it always showing incorrect qsub command or simply alway queued on cluster because of input args are wrong.

It must be the escaping problem, my question is how to escape the command above properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, however their methods will not work on my case. I have to answer this by myself since this problem is pretty complex, I got the clue from existing solutions in stackoverflow.

There are 2 problems must be solved in my case.

1. Pass local program's parameters to the remote cluster. Here-doc solution doesn't work in this case.
2. Run qsub on remote cluster with the a long variable as arguments that contain quote symbol.

**Problem 1.**

Firstly, I have to introduce my script that runs on local machine takes parameters like this:

```
scripttoberunoncluster.py --source-organisation "My_organization_my_department" --project-name "MyProjectName"  --processes 4 /targetoutputfolder/
```

The real parameter is far more longer than above, so all the parameter must be sent to remote. They are sent in file like this:

```
PROJECT_NAME="MyProjectName"
PACK_ORGANIZATION="--source-organization '\\\"My_organization_my_department\\\"'" # multiple layers of escaping, remove all the spaces
PROJECT_NAME_PACK="--project-name '\\\"${PROJECT_NAME}\\\"'"
PROCESSES_="--processes 4"
TARGET_FOLDER_PACK="/targetoutputfolder/"

INPUTARGS="${PACK_ORGANIZATION} ${PROJECT_NAME_PACK} ${PROCESSES} ${TARGET_FOLDER_PACK}"

echo $INPUTARGS > "TempPath/temp.par"
scp "TempPath/temp.par" "remotecluster:/remotepath/"
```

My solution is sort of compromising. But in this way the remote cluster can run script with arguments contain quote symbol. If you don't put all your variable (as parameters) in a file and transfer it to remote cluster, no matter how you pass them into variable, the quote symbol will be removed.

**Problem 2.**

Check how the qsub runs on remote cluster.

```
ssh remotecluster "qsub -v argv=\"`cat /remotepath/temp.par`\" -l walltime=10:00:00 /remotepath/my.script"
```

And in the my.script:

```
INPUT_ARGS=`echo $argv`

python "/pythonprogramlocation/scripttoberunoncluster.py" $INPUT_ARGS ; #note: $INPUT_ARGS hasn't quote
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this using a *here-doc* : you have a quote conflict (nested double quotes that is an error):

```
#!/bin/bash

PROJECT_NAME_TEXT="TEST PROJECT"
PACK_ORGANIZATION="--source-organization \'MY, ORGANIZATION\'"
CONTACT_NAME="--contact-name \'Tom Riddle\'"
PROJECT_NAME_PACK="--project-name \"${PROJECT_NAME_TEXT}\""


INPUTARGS="${PACK_ORGANIZATION} ${CONTACT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME_PACK}"

ssh mycluster <<EOF
qsub -v argv="$INPUTARGS" -l walltime=10:00:00 -l vmem=8GB -l nodes=1:ppn=4 /myscript_path/run.script
EOF
```

As you can see, *here-docs* are really helpful for inputs with quotes.

See [`man bash | less +/'Here Documents'`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents)

### Edit

from your comments :

---

> I used this method but it gives me "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."

You can ignore this warning with

```
ssh mycluster <<EOF 2>/dev/null
```

(try the `-t` switch for `ssh` if needed)

---

If you have

> `-bash: line 2: EOF: command not found`

I think you have a copy paste problem. Try to remove extra spaces on all end lines

---

> And it seems this method cannot pass local variable `$INPUTARGS` to the remote cluster

it seems related to your `EOF` problem.

---

> `$argv` returns nothing on remote cluster

What does this means ? `$argv` is not a pre-defined variable in `bash`. If you need to list command line arguments, use the pre-defined variable `$@`

---

Last thing : ensure you are using `bash`

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know you could use heredoc in bash; I shall have to remember that...

Comment: I used this method but it gives me "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.", and "-bash: line 2: EOF: command not found"

Comment: And it seems this method cannot pass local variable $INPUTARGS to the remote cluster, $argv returns nothing on remote cluster.

Comment: @sputnick,Yes, thanks for answer and edit. I tried lots of method these 2 days, but end up using another method to pass local variable to remote, my actual problem is that I have to use the parameter contain quotes symbol, and in bash this will be always removed. I'll post the working final solution, no one did it on stack overflow I think.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the length, but the nesting of your quotes - in this line, you are trying to use `"` inside `"`, which won't work:

```
ssh mycluster "qsub -v argv="$INPUTARGS" -l walltime=10:00:00 -l vmem=8GB -l nodes=1:ppn=4 /myscript_path/run.script"
```

Bash will see this as `"qsub -v argv="` followed by `$INPUTARGS` (not quoted), followed by `" -l walltime=10:00:00 -l vmem=8GB -l nodes=1:ppn=4 /myscript_path/run.script"`.

It's possible that backslash-escaping those inner quotes will have the desired effect, but nesting quotes in bash can get rather confusing. What I often try to do is add an `echo` at the beginning of the command, to show how the various stages of expansion pan out. e.g.

```
echo 'As expanded locally:'
echo ssh mycluster "qsub -v argv=\"$INPUTARGS\" -l walltime=10:00:00 -l vmem=8GB -l nodes=1:ppn=4 /myscript_path/run.script"
echo 'As expanded remotely:'
ssh mycluster "echo qsub -v argv=\"$INPUTARGS\" -l walltime=10:00:00 -l vmem=8GB -l nodes=1:ppn=4 /myscript_path/run.script"
```

Answer (score 0):

The described escaping problem consists in the requirement to preserve final quotes around arguments after **two** evaluation processes, i. e. after two evaluations we should see something like:

```
--source-organization "My_organization_my_department" --project-name "MyProjectName" --processes 4 /targetoutputfolder/
```

This can be achieved codewise by first putting each argument in a separate variable and then enclosing the argument with single quotes while making sure that possible single quotes inside the argument string get "escaped" with `'\''` (in fact, the argument will be split up into separate strings but, when used, the split-up argument will automatically get re-concatenated by the string evaluation mechanism of UNIX (POSIX?) shells). And this procedure has to be repeated **three** times.

```
{
escsquote="'\''"

PROJECT_NAME="MyProjectName"

myorg="My_organization_my_department"
myorg="'${myorg//\'/${escsquote}}'" # bash
myorg="'${myorg//\'/${escsquote}}'"
myorg="'${myorg//\'/${escsquote}}'"
PACK_ORGANIZATION="--source-organization ${myorg}"

pnp="${PROJECT_NAME}"
pnp="'${pnp//\'/${escsquote}}'"
pnp="'${pnp//\'/${escsquote}}'"
pnp="'${pnp//\'/${escsquote}}'"
PROJECT_NAME_PACK="--project-name ${pnp}"

PROCESSES="--processes 4"
TARGET_FOLDER_PACK="/targetoutputfolder/"

INPUTARGS="${PACK_ORGANIZATION} ${PROJECT_NAME_PACK} ${PROCESSES} ${TARGET_FOLDER_PACK}"

echo "$INPUTARGS"
eval echo "$INPUTARGS" 
eval eval echo "$INPUTARGS"
echo
ssh -T localhost <<EOF
echo qsub -v argv="$INPUTARGS" -l walltime=10:00:00 -l vmem=8GB -l nodes=1:ppn=4 /myscript_path/run.script
EOF

}
```

For further information please see:

- [Quotes exercise - how to do ssh inside ssh whilst running sql inside second ssh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55049/55108)
- [Quoting in ssh $host $FOO and ssh $host "sudo su user -c $FOO" type constructs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4770/55108).