# How to pass local variable to remote using ssh and bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh, cluster-computing

```
ssh remotecluster 'bash -s' << EOF
> export TEST="sdfsd"
> echo $TEST
> EOF
```

This prints nothing.

Also it still does not work even if I store the variable into file and copy it to remote.

```
TEST="sdfsdf"
echo $TEST > temp.par
scp temp.par remotecluster
ssh remotecluster 'bash -s' << EOF
> export test2=`cat temp.par`
> echo $test2
> EOF
```

Still prints nothing.

So my question is how to pass local variable to the remote machine as a variable ?

Answers have been give in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775911/how-to-properly-escaping-qsub-command-with-long-input-args-within-ssh-command#15776073)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable assignment `TEST="sdfsd"` given in the here document is no real variable assignment, i. e. the variable assignment will actually not be performed directly in the declaration / definition of the here document (but later when the here document gets evaluated by a shell).

In addition, the `$TEST` variable contained in an unescaped or unquoted here document will be expanded by the **local shell** before the local shell executes the `ssh` command.
The result is that `$TEST` will get resolved to the empty string if it is not defined in the local shell **before** the `ssh` command or the here document respectively.

As a result, the variable assignment `export TEST="sdfsd"` in the here document will not take effect in the local shell, but first be sent to the shell of the remote host and only there be expanded, hence your *prints nothing* experience.

The solution is to use an escaped or single-quoted here document, `<<\EOF` or `<<'EOF'`; or only escape the `\$TEST` variable in the here document; or just define the `$TEST` variable before the `ssh` command (and here document).

```
# prints sdfsd
export TEST="sdfsd"
ssh localhost 'bash -s' << EOF
echo $TEST
EOF

# prints sdfsd
ssh localhost 'bash -s' << EOF
export TEST="sdfsd"
echo \$TEST
EOF

# prints sdfsd
ssh localhost 'bash -s' <<'EOF'
export TEST="sdfsd"
echo $TEST
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I want to add my two cents to this in case anyone's not familiar with here docs. I just want to add to Carlo's post, with the heredoc add the variable with the ssh session and maybe do the quotes differently:

```
TEST="sdfsd"
ssh remotehost bash -s "$TEST" <<-'HEREDOC'
    export $1
    echo $1
HEREDOC
```

Most people want to change a variable and not hard code it in the heredoc, I find that works for me usually, but someone should verify. Also mind the "tabs" if you used <<-, and avoid spaces. Spaces always get me, so tab over. If it fails, take out the dash and tabs.

Answer (score 0):

export variable, ssh send exported(environment) variables to server
export VAR=test
ssh -v 127.0.0.1  echo $VAR
test above commands and see result

Comment: The remote server must be configured to allow the local environment to be sent to the remote session.